# Не парсится сайт. Лог непонятен

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Нужно собрать ссылки со всего сайта в файл. Нашел вот это на этом сайте. Почему-то не работает (находит только одну ссылку). Писал автору - без ответа. Помогите исправить

```
import io
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pages_to_parse=['https://www.site.ru/']
parsed_pages=[]
site_links=[]

while pages_to_parse != []:
    current_page = pages_to_parse.pop()
    html_doc = urlopen('https://www.site.ru/').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

    # ищем div с нужным классом
    collect = soup.find('body')
    # в найденном div'е, ищем все ссылки (т.е. теги a).
    a_tags_on_page = collect.findAll('a')
    links_on_page = []
    for link in a_tags_on_page:
        links_on_page.append(link.get('href'))

    parsed_pages.append(current_page)
    for i in links_on_page:
        if i not in site_links:
            site_links.append(i)
        if i not in parsed_pages:
            pages_to_parse.append(i)
    links_on_page = []


f = io.open('parsed_data.htm', 'w', encoding='utf8')
i = 0
# запишем в файл
while i < len(site_links):
    f.write(""+str(i)+"<a href='"+str(site_links[i]).decode('utf-8')+"'></a><br/>")
    i = i+1
f.close()
```

Выдает вот такой лог:

> C:/PycharmProjects/testby/ParserURL.py:16: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.
>
> The code that caused this warning is on line 16 of the file C:/PycharmProjects/testby/ParserURL.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.
>
> ```
> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
> ```

Comment: Так как вы не показали, что именно парсите, то я со всей уверенностью могу заявить, что на странице на самом деле ровно одна ссылка и с кодом никаких проблем нет

Comment: Можно проще: 1) `while pages_to_parse != []:` -> `while pages_to_parse:` 2) `while i < len(site_links):` -> `for i in range(len(site_links)):`, `i = 0` и `i = i+1` удалить, либо использовать enumerate: `for i, link in enumerate(site_links):`. Думаю, еще можно найти, что отрефакторить, но тут уж лучше отдельным вопросом с меткой "инспекция-кода" спрашивать :)

Comment: @ gil9red Прошу прощения. ссылки всех страниц сайта

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` умеет работать с разными парсерами, но если не указывать конкретный, то пишет предупреждение и на свое усмотрение выбирает парсер.

---

Попробуйте `html.parser`, он является стандартным парсером питона:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

Либо как захотел `BeautifulSoup` – `lxml`. Но его нужно будет устанавливать, если его нет (`pip install lxml`):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
```

Comment: @ gil9red С вариантом html.parser код отрабатывает, но файл пустой. ошибок не дает. А с вариантом lxml зависает и все. никаких действий не происходит

Comment: urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10013] Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом, запрещенным правами доступа> Вот такое в логе получаю

Comment: @СергейБогданов . Если что не так получается, пробуйте разобраться сами, например выведя `html_doc` и смотря что не так :) С `urlopen` не работал -- в основном через `requests`, например: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/33004e4a5bf79f2618b3ef255a872b04536b50dc/html_parsing/vitaly_zykov_ru_knigi__get_books.py#L15 А так, ваша текущая проблема связана с urlopen, возможно еще с тем сайтом. Попробуйте через requests. Если не получится -- создайте новый вопрос по новой проблеме, т.к. для текущей вопрос решен, а обсуждение новой -- флуд. Кст, если мой ответ помог, примите его :)

Comment: @  gil9red да, спасибо. Ответ помог.

Comment: @СергейБогданов, если ответ помог -- примите его. Слева будет галочка :)

Answer (score 1):

Во первых в определении класса BeautifulSoup укажите нужный парсер.

Во вторых используйте функцию soup.findAll(), а не soup.find()

В третьих попробуйте достать нужные данные этим способом с помощью библиотеки requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result=''
page = requests.get('http://google.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
# Вместо page.content можно page.text
# именно page.text, а не просто page как у вас

''' # Первый вариант
for tag in soup.findAll('a'): # Определенный тэг
# Если надо все, то функции findAll передаем 'html'
    result += str(tag['href'])# Определенный атрибут
    # Можно просто str(tag) # Это все тэги
'''
# Более производительный вариант получения результата от юзера @gil9red
result = ''.join(str(tag) for tag in soup.findAll('html'))

print(result)
```

Comment: Лучше `page.text` -> `page.content`. В этом случае ответственность за кодирования в строку ляжет на bs4, но с `.text` тоже работать будет. Да и result можно в одну строку заполнить и это будет эффективнее (т.к. конкатенация строк выполняется через создание новой строки): `result = ''.join(str(tag) for tag in soup.findall('html'))`

Comment: @FedotSoldier Вот такой лог после Вашей версии дает

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/testby/parserdub.py", line 8, in <module>
    for tag in soup.findall('html'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Сори, неправильно написал имя функции. Не findall, а findAll. Ответ исправил. Скопируйте и попробуйте еще раз. Спасибо @gil9red за предложенный вариант. Его тоже возьмите на вооружение.