# Нужно спарсить 1000 ссылок адресов web-сайтов содержащих Google Adsense рекламу

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Мне нужно спарсить 1000 ссылок адресов web-сайтов содержащих Google Adsense рекламу. Только начал изучать Python. Подскажите с чего начать?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Например: requests + bs4. Пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/html_parsing/get_set_sushi_list__sushivkusno.com.py

Comment: Начните с [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Спасибо, коллеги. А есть пример кода , как определить сайт с Google Adsense?

Answer (score 1):

Вот вопрос про парсинг: [Не парсится сайт. Лог непонятен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/882144/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD/882804?noredirect=1#comment1437306_882804)

А вот видеоурок по созданию парсер - бота: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psDbHgltX_Y&t=927s

Разузнайте про модули requests, bs4, urllib

Удачи!